# How To emulate MySQL Function with OUT parameter

Tags: mysql, syntax, parameters

As far as I understand MySQL [does not support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) functions with `OUT` (as well as `IN` / `INOUT`) parameter types.
I am creating a function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GETGOSTAUTHRUS`;

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GETGOSTAUTHRUS`(`PublID` int)
 RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN 

    RETURN .....;
END;
```

This function is called from `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
GETGOSTAUTHRUS(p.ID) `AuthList`,.......
FROM....
```

Everything works fine. However I need to extend the function and return another value of varchar type but I can not declare `out prefix varchar(50)` variable in the same way as I do in procedure declaration:

```
CREATE procedure `GETGOSTAUTHRUS`(PublID int, OUT prefix varchar(50))

BEGIN
```

The only way out I have invented is to declare another function and call it separately, but it seems not optimal as the second function will fetch and process the same data from the tables.

How can I manage the issue?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Comment: @ColourDalnet Yes, thank you. It is almost the same as in the article available from the link in my Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are supposed to return only one value, you might have the wrong approach here. We don't know what you're exactly trying to do, so we can't tell if we're dealing with a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. There may be better solutions to your overall problem.

You can solve this however with [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). These are session bound, so make sure to reset them in your function.

Comment: Thank you! This is not an XY-problem, but the second part of your question is helpful! I shall consider transfering the value in `@somevariable`